# Expressjs and node-cassandra-cql post taking ~120000ms

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra

[image: screenshot from 2014-05-24 10 54 07]

I dont know what is happening sometimes cassandra is easily committing the post and storing data in ~20ms and other times the post takes ~120000ms but the post is not committed(i.e stored). Any Suggestion Guys i'm struggling with this for two days
I dont find any error in the bellow queries . I have indexed checked column.

Here is my main app file:

```
 var express=require('express'),
app=express(),
morgan=require('morgan'),
bodyParser=require('body-parser'),
methodOverride=require('method-override'),
cookieParser=require('cookie-parser'),
sessions=require('express-session'),
passport=require('passport'),
path=require('path'),
cassandra=require('node-cassandra-cql'),
port=3000;

 var cassandraSettings=require('./config/cassandra').setting;
 cassandraClient = new cassandra.Client(cassandraSettings);
 cassandraClient.connect(function(error){
if(error)
    console.log('error - ' + error);
else
    console.log('Logged In to Cassandra');
 });



var cassandraConfig={
readConsistency:cassandra.types.consistencies.one,
writeConsistency:cassandra.types.consistencies.any,
cassandra:cassandra,
cassandraClient:cassandraClient
}

require('./config/passport')(passport,cassandraConfig);

app.use(morgan('dev'))
.use(bodyParser())
.use(methodOverride())
.use(cookieParser())
.use(sessions({name:"sid",cookie:{maxAge:1000*60*60*24*30},secret:"Ankit"}))
.use(passport.initialize())
.use(passport.session());




//url for statics
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

 require('./routes/login')(app,passport);
 require('./routes/signup')(app,passport);
 //Used to insert Sport, League, TeamDetails 
  require('./routes/private/insert_sport_detail')(app,cassandraConfig);
 //require('./routes/private/insert_league_detail')(app,cassandraConfig);

 app.listen(port);
```

My cassandra route.js:

```
  var queries={
insert:{
    sport_detail:{
        query:'INSERT INTO only_sport_detail(sportid,sport_name,sport_short_name,time_made,checked) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'
    },
    league_detail:{
        query:'INSERT INTO only_league_detail(leagueid,league_name,league_short_name,league_abbreviation,league_location,time_made,checked) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    }
},
retrieve:{
    sport_detail:{
        query:'SELECT * FROM only_sport_detail WHERE checked=?'
    },
    league_detail:{
        query:'SELECT * FROM only_league_detail WHERE checked=?'
    }
}
 };

   module.exports=function(app,cassandraConfig){
var cassandraClient=cassandraConfig.cassandraClient;
var writeConsistency=cassandraConfig.writeConsistency;
var readConsistency=cassandraConfig,readConsistency;
var cassandra=cassandraConfig.cassandra;
app.get('/insert/detail/sport',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('views/insert/sport_detail.html');
});
app.post('/insert/detail/sport',function(req,res){
    sportid=cassandra.types.timeuuid();
    cassandraClient.executeAsPrepared(
        queries.insert.sport_detail.query,
        [sportid,req.body.sport_name,req.body.sport_short_name,{value: new Date(), hint: cassandra.types.dataTypes.timestamp},1],
        writeConsistency,
        function(err){
            if(!err)
            {

                cassandraClient.executeAsPrepared(
                    queries.retrieve.sport_detail.query,
                    [1],
                    function(err,result){
                        if(err)
                        {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.send('Sorry error');
                            res.end();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            res.json(result.rows);
                            res.end();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );

});

app.get('/get/detail/sport',function(req,res){
    cassandraClient.executeAsPrepared(
        queries.retrieve.sport_detail.query,
        [1],
        function(err,result){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                res.send('Sorry error');
                res.end();
            }
            else
            {
                res.json(result.rows);
                res.end();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

};

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause?

Comment: yes use some kind of data flow module like `async.js` and you will find the answer. basically it happens because everything in node is asycn and what control flow i predicted was wrong